# SHELL save file from link to disk

Tags: shell, hyperlink, download, background

I have a website with a link (file to download) with which I can download a file (zip). When I click on the link it opens a window to save the file. I want to do this with a shellscript and run this tasks in the background (open site, click link, choose path /home/Downloads/ for destination).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
!/usr/bin/sh
wget /pathwheretosave/filename websiteurl/filename
```

The **wget** command is a command line utility for downloading files from Internet

If you use `wget -O /pathwheretosave/newfilename websiteurl/filename`
 will make you able download a file and change the name.

To execute in background you can launch the script in **nohup**

```
nohup filename.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use curl to download the link direct. In the windows powershell as follows. Should be very similar if not identical on *nix:

```
curl -Uri http://domain/file.zip -OutFile ~/Downloads/file.zip
```

Comment: -U is a command to download a file from an ftp server. But I don't have the user or hostname. Is there a nother way?